# Snapshot tests with Styled-Components fail in the CI pipeline due to different class index

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, styled-components, react-testing-library

I am using `react-testing-library` and `jest-styled-components` to do snapshot tests. It has been working fine before but now the snapshot tests of many components are failing in the CI pipeline (Gitlab) just because of a different index in the hashed class name placeholders generated by `jest-styled-components`:

```
   - Snapshot
+ Received

@@ -1,19 +1,19 @@
- .c4 {
+ .c3 {
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    min-height: 14px;
    min-width: 14px;
    width: 14px;
  }

- .c4 > svg {
+ .c3 > svg {
    fill: currentColor;
    pointer-events: none;
  }

- .c4 > svg * {
+ .c3 > svg * {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .c2 .ant-calendar-picker-input.ant-input {
@@ -26,15 +26,15 @@

  .c0 {
    position: relative;
  }

- .c3 {
+ .c4 {
    color: #00293a;
  }

- .c1 .c3 {
+ .c1 .c4 {
    color: #00293a;
  }

  <div>
    <div
@@ -49,11 +49,11 @@
            placeholder="Select date"
            readonly=""
            value=""
          />
          <div
-           class="ant-calendar-picker-icon c3 c4"
+           class="c3 c4 ant-calendar-picker-icon"
            data-testid="icon_arrowDown"
            size="14"
          >
            <file-mock />
          </div>

  21 |   it('renders correctly', () => {
  22 |     const { container } = renderWithProps()
> 23 |     expect(container).toMatchSnapshot()
     |                       ^
  24 |   })
  25 | })
  26 |
```

When running the tests locally, there is no problem.

Does someone have an idea about what is going wrong?

Comment: For styled components, minor version changes can result in changing of the class-index which is used in snapshots. Make sure the version numbers in package.json file are constant. If you need to be flexible with the hot fixes, then I'd suggest using `tilde (~)` instead of `caret(^)` against your package versions. To read more about versioning refer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/22345808/3609255

Answer (score 2):

Making sure the same versions of the packages are used locally and in the CI solved it.

After deleting node_modules and running the same install command as in the CI, running the tests  locally changed the snapshots. I updated the snapshots, committed and pushed the changes and the pipeline ran successfully.